# Usage of col() function in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Issue Description :

In the below code sample (1) works fine but (2) throws error . I checked the functions parameters in their definition , both said initcap(col) and upper(col) , Which I think means they will accept a Column Object , so why is there a difference in execution ? Adding col() upper() runs without error.

Code for generating Data :

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType , StructField , StringType 
from pyspark.sql.functions import col , upper , initcap
myRow = Row('this is spark')

myManualSchema = StructType([
StructField('Description',StringType())
])

myDF = spark.createDataFrame([myRow],myManualSchema)
myDF.show()
```

Code for Issue Replication

```
myDF.select(initcap('Description')).show(2)     # (1) Works Fine

myDF.select(upper('Description')).show(2)       # (2) Error

myDF.select(upper(col('Description'))).show(2)  # (3) Works Fine
```

(1)
[Image for Point 1 :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQ9aT.png)

(2)
[Image for Point 2 :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ii2U.png)

(3)
[Image for Point 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEYNo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected behavior for `upper(col)` and `lower(col)` functions. If you go through the [PySpark source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/fa378567105ec9d9bbe30edf4b74b09c3df27658/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py#L1884), you would see an explicit conversion of string to column for `initcap(col)` function, but there there is no Python wrapper written for `upper(col)` and `lower(col)` functions.

```py
def initcap(col):
    """Translate the first letter of each word to upper case in the sentence.
    >>> spark.createDataFrame([('ab cd',)['a']).select(initcap("a").alias('v')).collect()
    [Row(v=u'Ab Cd')]
    """
    sc = SparkContext._active_spark_context
    return Column(sc._jvm.functions.initcap(_to_java_column(col)))
```

Same-way, if you check the underlying [Scala code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/590b9a0132b68d9523e663997def957b2e46dfb1/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala#L2684) for the above functions, you would see they accept `Column` as argument.

Comment: Thanks for your help here @Kondasamy . It was insightful to know that some functions have a python wrapper while others dont , this is where the difference need to be looked. One takeaway will be to look into the source code directly for better understanding .Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

If you check Spark SQL functions documentation you can see that upper function receives a col object, not string:

[Spark upper docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.upper)